# How can I convert data in multiple columns one after the other?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, unpivot

How can I convert the data in the image to the bottom?

[Example Table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XW88tdCrmQm7MBeb7Py8l0qbMatZUe4iKYL0-VO3m8M/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a new column, you can use below formula to get the month where it has value greater than 0

```
=IF(I2>0,I1,IF(J2>0,J1,IF(K2>0,K1,"no value")))
```

You can repeat the column until "T" (December) for every row increment the cell reference
For eg.

```
=IF(I3>0,I1,IF(J3>0,J1,IF(K3>0,K1,"no value")))
```